# Data from database don't show in my edit page

Tags: php, mysql, sql, web, sql-update

Everything's working fine now. I can now view and update my data from my database. Thank you for helping me out. I already updated the code below. Thank you :)

**edit_news.php** // this is where the contents from my database to show to be able to update

```
    <?php
        mysql_connect("localhost", "root");
        mysql_select_db("alumni");
        if(isset($_GET['edit_id']))
        {

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM news WHERE id=".$_GET['edit_id']; 
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

?>
<form action="/admin/update_news.php" method="post">
<div>
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo  $row['id'] ?>"/>
<input type="text" name="title" value="<?php echo $row['title']; ?> "/>
<input type="text" name="body" value="<?php echo $row['body']; ?>"/>

<input type="submit" name="update" value="Save Changes"/>
<input type="submit" name="cancel" value="Cancel"/>

</div>
</form>

<?php 
        }
        ?>
```

**update_news.php** // this is where the update function happens

```
    <?php 
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');
    include_once('db.php');
    if(isset($_POST['update']))
    {
        $title = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['title']));
        $body = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['body']));

        $sql = ("UPDATE news SET title='$title', body='$body' WHERE id=".$_POST['id']) or die(mysql_error());

            if(mysql_query($sql))
            {
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Changes saved!!');
                    window.location.assign('admin_profile.php');</script>";
            }
            else
            {
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Error while updating data.');
                    window.location.assign('admin_profile.php');</script>";
            }
    }
            if (isset($_POST['cancel']))
            {
                header("Location: admin_profile.php");
            }
?>
```

// this is where the user click the **edit** link that will lead them to edit_news.php

```
<a href="/admin/edit_news.php?edit_id=<?php echo $row[0]; ?>">EDIT</a>
```

Comment: Try `<a href="/admin/edit_news.php?id=" . $row['id'] . "">EDIT</a>`

Comment: You can't mix `mysql_` and `mysqli`.

Comment: You are not fetching data from db to the edit page.Id is being passed to edit_news,php but you are not using it.

Fetch data from db using that id to vriables $title and $body

Comment: I added this code to my edit_news.php `<?php include_once('db.php');
  $servername = "localhost";
  $username="root";
  $password = "";
  $database = "alumni";
  $connection = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);
  if ($connection->connect_error) {
   die("Connection failed: " . $connection->connect_error);
  }
  $id = $_POST['id'];
  $title = $_POST['title'];
  $body = $_POST['body'];
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM news WHERE id = $id";
  $result = $connection->query($sql);
  $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
?>` but it's still the same :( @jayadevkv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now you have removed input type hidden from form and used $_GET['id'] in update_news.php which again gone wrong.Add the field there again and use $_POST['id'] instead of $_GET['id'] in update_news.php

The rest looking fine now.

Comment: That just made it all right now! Thank you so so much for helping me out! Thank you @jayadevkv ! :D

Comment: glad i could help and thanks for the upvotes @eric :)

Answer (score 2):

You will get id in edit_news.php by

```
 $id = $_GET['id']
```

Then using that id fetch data from Database using select query to variables $title and $body

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM news WHERE id = $id";
```

Then populate form elements using values you got by issuing the query above using any of the mysql_fetch functions

Comment: and there is no need to include db.php if you are speciying database settings on the same page.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not sure if I got your point, but I did this anyway: `<?php
  $servername = "localhost";
  $username="root";
  $password = "";
  $database = "zchs_alumni";
  $connection = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);
  if ($connection->connect_error) {
   die("Connection failed: " . $connection->connect_error);
  }
  $id = $_GET['id'];
    
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM news WHERE id =$id"; 
  $result = $connection->query($sql); 
  $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC); 
  
  $title = $row['title'];
  $body = $row['body'];
?>`

Comment: but when i click "edit" , it's still the same. and i have a awrning : _Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in edit_news.php_ Thank you for trying to help me

Comment: Have you checked if  you are passing/getting id value correctly. Also check if the database settings are correct.
The error means that $result is not having the desired value.Please debug codes before $connection->query($sql) for any error

Comment: @eric change this line <a href="/admin/edit_news.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">EDIT</a> .
Store $row['id'] in a temp variable and use that variable in href section of anchor tag

Comment: I have updated my question, I can now view the data from my database but I did some changes (of course). Thanks for the help! :)